# Skip validation on date field but still run before_validate callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I've ended up with a little dilemma and I'm curious to hear what your general thoughts on this are and where I need to think different.

I have a model called **Post** which has a **published_date**. In certain tests I use FactoryGirl create to push this date back for statistics calculations etc. Now I would like to have a constraint so that can not push this date back at all. I've added the validation and the obvious problem is that I get a validation error on the tests I mentioned as well.

You could say that I could skip validation in the tests by doing a save(validation: false) but that results in the before_validation callback not running which in my case is important to set data correctly and make sure fields are filled in with data etc.

What are your takes on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [timecop gem](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) it allows you to manipulate time, so if you have a validation that doesn't allow past dates, you could travel back in time and then the `Time.now` would return the old time, and the validations would work fine

here's a silly sample of what you could do

```
Timecop.freeze(30.days.ago) do
  object = FactoryGirl.create(:some_object)
end

expect(object.created_at).to be <= 30.days.ago
```

Comment: I think this is an acceptable solution. I don't see anything wrong with first traveling back in time creating the posts instead of back dating them by direct attribute manipulation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can open the class before your spec file or in spec helper and override the `before_validation` method in `test` env. Like -

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    def method_before_Validation
      true
    end
end
```